# mysql update script problem. all txt is lower case just first letter is upper case

Tags: mysql

This are my text in mysql database.

```
Otok Pasman, Kraj
Otok pasman,Kraj
Otok Pasman , Kraj
Otok pasman, Kraj
Otok PASMAN, Kraj
```

How can i automatically change all rows to lower case, first letter must be upper case and " , " is always ", "?

so like this:

```
Otok Pasman, Kraj
```

and all other text in database like this example?

Comment: What do you mean `automatically` ?

Comment: why don't u do it with script language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `field` = REPLACE(CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(`field`, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(`field`, 2))),' , ', ', ')
```