# using mysql string functions

Tags: mysql

I have  a table with following Data in a table

```
abcd 
abcd , pgw 
ABcd , Pgw
```

I want output as

```
Abcd
Abcd , Pgw
Abcd , Pgw
```

the First letter in capitals and letter after ',' in capital.

Comment: You have to give us more information...

Comment: What about "one two, three"? Should it be "One Two, Three" or "One two, Three"?

Comment: why dont u change it via scripting language when your concern is only to display it??

Comment: @diEcho:i want to it using mysql

Comment: if u want to store into db then manipulate with mysql functions, otherwise it's not good practice to use mysql functions while display the data

Answer (score 2):

to make first letter upper-case use this

```
select CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(`field`, 1)), SUBSTRING(`field`, 2)) from mytable
```

to do it to also to word after comma declare a function like :

```
DELIMITER ||  

CREATE FUNCTION `ucwords`( str VARCHAR(128) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(128) CHARSET latin1  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);  
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);  
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;  
  DECLARE BOOL INT DEFAULT 1;        
  SET s = LCASE( str );  
  WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO  
     BEGIN  
       SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );  
       IF c = ',' THEN  
        SET BOOL = 1;  
      ELSEIF BOOL=1 THEN  
        BEGIN  
          IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN  
             BEGIN  
               SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));  
               SET BOOL = 0;  
             END;             
          END IF;  
        END;  
      END IF;  
      SET i = i+1;  
    END;  
  END WHILE;  
  RETURN s;  
END ||  

DELIMITER ;
```

and use

```
 select ucwords(`field`) from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this if you *ever* expect your database to scale well. If you're only ever going to be using this for your personal phone book application or equally tiny data sets, you can get away with doing this at `select` time, as you suggest.

But, if you want a robust scalable database, you should sacrifice space (disk storage) for time (speed). Per-row functions on select statement rarely scale well.

One time-honored and tested way of doing this is to add another column of identical specifications to the one you already have and use an insert/update trigger to populate it with the data in the format you desire.

Then the cost of the transformation is incurred only when you have to (when the data is updated), not every single time you read the data. This amortises the cost across the reads which, in the *vast* majority of databases, outweigh writes considerably.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238965/mysql-update-script-problem-all-txt-is-lower-case-just-first-letter-is-upper-cas/7239036#7239036) shows an SQL formula which seems close to what you want but I do strongly suggest that you use it in a trigger rather than inefficiently running it every `select`.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this solution [mysql-update-script-problem-all-txt-is-lower-case-just-first-letter-is-upper-cas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238965/mysql-update-script-problem-all-txt-is-lower-case-just-first-letter-is-upper-cas/7239036#7239036) , it should give you enough information to adapt to what you're trying to do. Change update to SELECT, etc. etc.

Comment: it was never a complete working solution, just trying to give you an idea of what you can do, you actually need to do a little bit of work yourself too. What exactly did you try that is not working? Post an update of what you tried exactly.